# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Diagrams with multiple parents

Tags: kendo-dataviz

I am trying to use Kendo dataviz diagrams in ASP.NET MVC to represent a hierarchy where each node can have more than one parent. Is this possible at all? And if so, how do you represent the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got a reply form Telerik and the answer is no.

Comment: Is this still true?
On the editor we can indeed create a node which has multiple parents but I cannot find anything about how to represent this type of diagram in data...